# Node.js: log ignored errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way in `node.js` to log all exceptions?

`process.on('uncaughtException')` is not enough for me, because I need to log all caught and uncaught exceptions, even if there was a `catch` somewhere in the code which just ignored/swallowed the error.

Do you guys think, it is possible in `node.js`?

Comment: Create a new console and direct the two output streams to files. If you are handling the errors then just add console.error( // your error... and you will then be logging all errors. See Node.js documents `Console.`

Comment: I know I can log all exceptions from node.js code, but now I'm looking for a solution to catch all exceptions without touching the part of the code where it was thrown.

Comment: If you are catching the errors and ignoring them you can not trace them.

Comment: Is modyfying node.js source an option?

Comment: I don't think so, @KubaWyrostek :)

Comment: If the app is catching exceptions and throwing them away (the thought of which makes me nauseous) and this is a 3rd party app which you have no control over then, unless Harry Potter wrote the compiler, it's going to take a bit of wizardry to get those errors logged - way beyond my muggle capabilities.

Comment: Thx, @James , I was just thinking about there could be some event, like `beforeExceptionThrown` on which I could bind a listener.

Comment: @Adam an exception is named aptly - it's a situation you *handle* rather than a situation you prevent. The compiler would need to know before it ran code that it is going to fail, now compilers already do this well at design time and that's what makes them great as they can spot potential issues before they make it into the app. However, trying to do that at runtime is a very different (and difficult) situation because determining whether or not code will throw depends on a multitude of factors, something which can't really be determined until the code actually runs.

Comment: @Adam it will be much easier if you could post your promise and how you wrote it.. :)

Comment: Also, think about the practicality of that? Even if the compiler *was* able to determine that an exception was going to throw, it would need to inject it's own handling code on pretty much every line of code *just in case* an exception was likely in order to raise this sort of event - your app size would practically double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One hacky way to do this is using debug context:

```
const vm = require('vm');

const Debug = vm.runInDebugContext('Debug'); // Obtain Debug object

Debug.setListener((type, _, e) => { // listen for all debug events
  if (type == Debug.DebugEvent.Exception) {
    console.log(e.exception().stack) // e is an event object
  }
});

Debug.setBreakOnException(); // this is required for Exception event to fire

try {
  throw new Error('bla');
} catch(e) {
  // ha
}
```

Warning: don't leave this code in production, use for debugging only.

Obviously, it won't call asynchronous errors, because they are not actually thrown, they are just created to passed to a callback.

Another way is to replace possible error constructors:

```
const OldError = Error;
const MyError = function(message) {
  const err = new OldError(message);
  OldError.captureStackTrace(err, MyError); // remove top frame from stack trace

  console.log(err.stack);

  return err;
}

MyError.prototype = Error.prototype; // Fix instanceof
global.Error = MyError;

try {
  throw new Error('bla');
} catch(e) {
}


new Error('blabla');
```

This way you can also handle asynchronous error, but won't see if something other than instance `Error` is thrown.

If you are interested only in promises and you are using native v8 promises, then you can try this:

```
const vm = require('vm');

const Debug = vm.runInDebugContext('Debug');

Debug.setListener((type, _, e) => {
  if (type == Debug.DebugEvent.PromiseEvent) {
    if (e.status() === -1) { // 0=pending, 1=resolved, -1=rejected
      console.log(e.value().value().stack);
    }
  }
});



Promise.reject(new Error('test'))
  .catch(() => {});
```

It will likely generate some duplicates, since it catches child promise rejection as well as original promise rejection.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a debugger like node-inspector and active the option [image: Pause on caught Exceptions] in node-inspector. This does not log exceptions but pause execution which should be enough to find the quirks in the 3rd party module.

If you're using WebStorm you can log uncaught exceptions to the console or to a file. After starting the WebStorm debugger open the breakpoints dialog and activate the "Any exception" setting for "JavaScript Exception Breakpoints" and breakpoint actions according to [image: this dialog]

Answer (score 0):

If you are swallowing the exceptions you cannot track them.
If you think that a module that you're using is ignoring the exceptions you are using a bad module or you are not using it correctly.

If you are using Express the correct approach will be to redirect all the exception and errors with `next(err)`.

The exceptions will be passed to the error handler (note the four parameters in the function) and there you can log them:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // your logic

    if(err) {
        return next(err);
    }


    return next();
});


// Error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    console.log(err.stack);

    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        error: {
            code: err.code,
            message: err.message
        }
    });

    next(err);
});
```

Comment: It won't log any error that was caught and ignored.

Comment: Of course, if you are ignoring it how can you log it?

Comment: This is my question. What can I do, if I have to work on a code that might ignore some exceptions?

Comment: You can't. If the exception is ignored it's just discarded. That's why is bad to ignore or swallow the exceptions. I cannot understand why you cannot just avoid to ignore the exception.

Comment: Because I'm working with 3rd party modules of thousands of lines of code, and I'm pretty sure, this module swallows some errors.

Comment: @downvoter, why downvote? This seems one common way to catch exception in Node.js....

Comment: @zangw I guess because it's not a specific answer to the question, but the question itself is impossible to answer. Anyway, you can still debug the module and see where it swallows the exception (it seems strange to me, maybe you're using a bad module or incorrectly. Which module is it? Can you post some code?).

Comment: @Adam, could you please let us know this 3rd module, we want to find how they did it?

Comment: Thanks @zangw, but it's not that easy. I'm using a lot modules, and a `promise` of mine is never resolved, nor rejected. I know, it can be caused by a lot of reasons, I was just curious about if my problem was caused by an ignored exception, would I have any chance to catch it somehow.

Comment: In my experience these kind of errors are almost never due to a bug in the modules or libraries but to a "bad" use of them. Maybe you should add the code where you have the problem and ask "this promise is not being resolved, why?"